# Symfony2 swift mailer how send

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm new on Symfony.. 
I would send an email with swift mailer but i don't understand if this service is enabled from FOSUserbundle or not..

I write this code in Controller:

```
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance();

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('----@---.com')
    ->setTo('----@---.com')
    ->setBody('You should see me from the profiler!')
;

// Pass a variable name to the send() method
if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
{
var_dump($failures);
}
```

IN config.yml i have this for FOSUserBundle

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }   

# Routing
be_simple_i18n_routing: ~

# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
    profile:
        form:
            type: dt_ec_profile
    registration:
        confirmation:
           enabled:    true
        form:
            type: dt_ec_registration
    from_email:
        address:        -----@----.com
        sender_name:    consulent
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    resetting:
        email:
            template: DtEcBundle:User:resetting.email.html.twig
```

How can i do for send and email? Thanks

Edit with parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: -----
    database_port: null
    database_name: ------
    database_user: root
    database_password: -------
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: it
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    domain: -----
    opentok_key: ----
    opentok_secret: -----
```

Comment: Your code seems to be good for send an email. What is the problem ?

Comment: @chalas_r for FOSUSERBUNDLE my code is good but i don't undestand beacuse doesn't work with another controller with this code.. How can i do?? I see the log but the email can't send

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 have an important principe, all components are standalone.

For each piece of Symfony you'll use, if you can see an available configuration for it in your `config.yml`, you must configure it. 
Especially if the configuration is empty.

As you can see in your `config.yml`, parameters are called instead of raw expressions.

In fact, a `parameters.yml` configuration file exists in the same directory (`config/`).
Your `config.yml` call it automatically to get parameters it need.
Set your e-mail configuration in your `parameters.yml`(password, user, host ..), 
and then you can use it in your bundles, including FOSUserBundle and other external bundles.

An example of swiftmailer configuration for local postfix :

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: your@email.fr
mailer_password: yourpwd
```

All you need to do the trick is in the documentation.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

Have a good experience with Symfony !